# Can I configure an S3 static site to redirect against an exact key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

I have a static site hosted on S3, including `/atom.xml`. In my access logs I see requests for `/feed` and `/atom` (no extension), so I'd like to redirect them.

I've set up redirect rules like this (as described by the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html)):

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition><KeyPrefixEquals>feed</KeyPrefixEquals></Condition>
    <Redirect><ReplaceKeyWith>atom.xml</ReplaceKeyWith></Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition><KeyPrefixEquals>atom</KeyPrefixEquals></Condition>
    <Redirect><ReplaceKeyWith>atom.xml</ReplaceKeyWith></Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

The first one (`feed -> atom.xml`) works just fine, but the second one (`atom -> atom.xml`) causes a redirect loop, because it's matching on the key *prefix*, not the whole key.

I tried making the matcher `atom/`, and that works if the request is to `/atom/`, but not to just `/atom`.

Is there a way to match the key a bit more intelligently?

Comment: could rename atom.xml to something with a different prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

Option 1. Don't redirect unless there is no matching object.

```
<RoutingRule>
  <Condition>
    <KeyPrefixEquals>atom</KeyPrefixEquals>  
    <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
  </Condition>
  <Redirect><ReplaceKeyWith>atom.xml</ReplaceKeyWith></Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

Note that you might find the required error code is 404 instead of 403, but if that is true, then your bucket is misconfigured and anybody can download the XML listing of all the objects in your bucket.  403 is definitely the correct code to use here, if the bucket configuration is not excessively open.

Option 2.  Use an empty object with redirect metadata.

Remove the redirect rule.

Upload an empty file named "atom" and set the following metadata:

```
x-amz-website-redirect-location: /atom.xml
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html